# jenkins endpoint in tfs 2015

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015, devops

I am trying to queue a build from tfs which was already setup on our Jenkins server by adding a build step called queue a Jenkins job in TFS ci pipeline. for this to happen we need to create a Jenkins endpoint first. when I tried configuring the Jenkins endpoint and verifying the connection to the jenkins [image]
server it says

> "The operation has timed out.

Note: Verification may fail if the URL is not accessible from Visual Studio Team Services. However it might still be valid and accessible from the agent that executes Build/Release." provided my jenkins server url, username and password.
 any help is highly appreciated

Comment: all i need is to establish a jenkins end point to queue a build in jenkins from tfs

Comment: Does the work fine with Jenkins Queue Job?

Answer (score 1):

Don’t worry about the connection verify error if you are using on premise build agent that can access your Jenkins server. Just click OK to save the configuration, then add Jenkins Queue Job step/task to your build definition and queue build with on premise build agent.